# How to improve a PyO3 interface to a generic struct?

Tags: rust, pyo3

I've created a Rust library to use from Python to do some heavy processing. It works fairly well but I'm left with code that feels bloated and hard to maintain, so I figure there must be a better way. I've tried a few different options using a variety of traits and enums but struggled to make any real improvement. I haven't done that much Rust so I'm guessing (and hoping) that I'm missing a nice, clean solution.

The rust package is basically just a single, core struct containing some data and quite a lot of implemented methods. This then gets wrapped by a pyclass struct to handle the interface to Python. The core struct needs to be generic, or at least the final python class needs to be able to handle several different data types. Further complicating it is that I use the core struct in other Rust projects and so I wanted to keep anything python related out of the core struct.

I ended up using a series of giant macros to create a few interface structs, one to handle each different data type. It's these macros that I find very difficult to work with but I haven't come up with a way of simplifying or removing them. So if anyone has any ideas or tips about where to go from here, that would be very much appreciated.

This is an extremely simplified version of my code:

```
// main.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;

pub mod core;
pub mod interface;

use interface::{FloatClass, IntClass, StrClass};

#[pymodule]
fn pyo3_test(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<FloatClass>()?;
    m.add_class::<IntClass>()?;
    m.add_class::<StrClass>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
// core.rs
pub struct Core<T> {
    pub data: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Core<T> {
    pub fn a(&self) {
        println!("running: a");
    }
    pub fn b(&self) {
        println!("running: b");
    }
    // lots more methods...
    pub fn z(&self) {
        println!("running: z");
    }
}
```

```
// interface.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;

use crate::core::Core;

macro_rules! create_interface {
    ($name: ident, $type: ident) => {
        #[pyclass]
        pub struct $name {
            pub inner: Core<$type>,
        }
        #[pymethods]
        impl $name {
            #[new]
            pub fn from_vector(data: Vec<$type>) -> Self {
                Self { inner: Core { data: data } }
            }
            pub fn a(&self) {
                self.inner.a()
            }
            pub fn b(&self) {
                self.inner.b()
            }
            // need to implement each method here as well
            // often using conversions to/from python types
            pub fn z(&self) {
                self.inner.z()
            }
        }
    };
}

create_interface!(IntClass, i64);
create_interface!(FloatClass, f64);
create_interface!(StrClass, String);
```

The methods implemented in the interface are obviously far more complex and unique than in this example, so generalising the interface methods would be difficult.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Since you already have working code and are asking for ways to improve it, this question would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jmb, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @JulesSJ, apologies for the necro here - would you be willing to share your library? I'm facing exactly the same problem, and I'm really curious to see what you came up with.

Comment: @Stuart, I didn't really make any further progress. Unfortunately, I haven't had the time available to keep playing with the structure of this project as it does actually work. I haven't even had a look recently for any helpful new features in PyO3. If I make any progress I'll definitely post here. I would of course be very happy if someone else fixed my problem for me, so good luck!